# How to make a clean and short code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm pretty new here on Stack Overflow and this is my first time asking a question so please be kind to me if you find this question stupid or anything.

Does anyone know how can I make these codes short, I mean I would like to put all these codes into one line.. Please see the code below.

```
Private Sub PB_SearchP_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PB_SearchP.MouseHover
    PB_SearchP.Image = My.Resources.search1
End Sub

Private Sub PB_SearchP_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PB_SearchP.MouseLeave
    PB_SearchP.Image = My.Resources.search
End Sub

Private Sub PB_AddP_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PB_AddP.MouseHover
    PB_AddP.Image = My.Resources.add_1_iconhover
End Sub

Private Sub PB_AddP_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PB_AddP.MouseLeave
    PB_AddP.Image = My.Resources.add_1_icon
End Sub

Private Sub PB_New_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PB_New.MouseHover
    PB_New.Image = My.Resources.newhover
End Sub

Private Sub PB_New_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PB_New.MouseLeave
    PB_New.Image = My.Resources.neww
End Sub

Private Sub PB_Save_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Save.MouseHover
    Btn_Save.Image = My.Resources.savehover
End Sub

Private Sub PB_Save_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Save.MouseLeave
    Btn_Save.Image = My.Resources.save
End Sub

Private Sub PB_Update_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_QUpdate.MouseHover
    BTN_QUpdate.Image = My.Resources.edithover
End Sub

Private Sub PB_Update_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_QUpdate.MouseLeave
    BTN_QUpdate.Image = My.Resources.edit
End Sub
```

Comment: Derive your own class from Button and override the OnMouseXxx() methods.  So you don't need *any* of these event handlers.

Comment: @HansPassant Deriving from `Button` seems overkill - OP only seems interested in automating `Image` property.

Comment: Strange that programmers find this 'scary' or overkill.  Inheritance is *crucial* in winforms to use the class library effectively.  Not having to write an event handler is a feature, not overkill, and very well supported.  If you don't like inheritance then WPF is the better alternative.

Comment: @HansPassant Even by subclassing `Button` to add image-swap-on-hover, each button subclass instance still needs to have the button images manually set on it - granted, the winforms designer could speed this up, but if you have to manually mutate each button you might as well just use event-handlers - especially because subclassing GUI components generally comes with caveats regarding correct override implementation (e.g. exactly when to call the parent implementation) which might break future-compatibility (e.g. `OwnerDraw` hell in WinForms)

Comment: Assigning the Image property requires code, key is that you only write it **once**.  Writing a bunch of AddHandler statements is not once.  There are no caveats, just a need to think about it a little bit.  It will only ever be a caveat if you never had to think about it before.

Comment: Hi, Hans Passant can you please provide an example on how i can do it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution is to use a function that sets-up lamba functions as event-handlers:

```
Public Shared Sub SetUpButton(btn As Button, normalImage As Image, hoverImage as Image)

    AddHandler btn.MouseLeave, Sub(o, e) btn.Image = normalImage
    AddHandler btn.MouseHover, Sub(o, e) btn.Image = hoverImage

End Sub
```

Called like so:

```
SetUpButton( Btn_Save, My.Resources.save, My.Resources.savehover )
SetUpButton( Btn_Update, My.Resources.update, My.Resources.updatehover )
SetUpButton( Btn_New, My.Resources.new, My.Resources.newhover )
```

and so on...

In C#, for a syntax comparison:

```
public static void SetUpButton(Button btn, Image normalImage, Image hoverImage) {
    btn.MouseLeave += (o,e) => btn.Image = normalImage;
    btn.MouseHover += (o,e) => btn.Image = hoverImage;
}
```